# how to display two div's right side one by one in html

Tags: html, css

Hi in the below code i want to display like this

```
Welcome Guest       Free Register   Login
drop down menu
Powered by Translate
```

the above all the text not displaying right hand side.

But when i am displaying the code my output is like this:

```
dropdown   Powered by Translate                      Welcome Guest       Free Register   Login
```

**html**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">


        <div class="header-right">

        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;Welcome Guest&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;Free Register
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Login
     </p>
     <div>
     <select>
     <option>Select Language</option>
     <option>English</option>

     </select>
     <p>Powered by Google Translate</p>
      </div>
        </div>
```

**style.css**

```
.logo {
  float: left;
}
.logo a {
  display: block;
}
.header {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.header-right p {
  float: right;
  width: 42%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

updated link:

```
see my site link `olisvell.com/responsivedesign/index.html` language also i want to display right
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding you last comment (try to edit you question if it changes a bit), you should move your `<div id="logo">` from `#navigation` to `.container` like this and change some CSS

```css
.container{ direction: ltr }
.header-right, .header-right .right{ float: right }
.header-right span{ margin-left: 20px }
.clear{ clear: both }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-right">
            <p class="right">Welcome Guest<span>Free Register</span><span>Login</span></p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <select class="right">
                <option>Select Language</option>
                <option>English</option>
            </select>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p class="right">Powered by Google Translate</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.gif" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to move select langaue and powerd by also right side

Comment: see my site link olisvell.com/responsivedesign/index.html language also i want to display right

Comment: see my link logo down

Comment: what do u want? logo inline with those stuff? I mean u want ur logo to go up ?

Comment: logo and text in a same line .yes logo i want to up

Comment: both navigation menu and logo i want to move to top

Answer (score 0):

Use a structure like this to get what you want:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="floating"></div>
    <div class="floating"></div>
    <br style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

and in your css:

```
.floating{
    float: left;
}
```

That will give you three divs side by side as you requested. Adjust width of container and floating divs to the size you want (sum of floating <= container) and but any content that will follow after the br tag, 
.

Comment: see my site link http://olisvell.com/responsivedesign/index.html language also i want to display right

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the floating to the right if you want them to stack. this will render it exactly.
https://jsfiddle.net/up5e3d60/

```
.header-right p {
width: 42%;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: But i want to display the full content in right side because of i was added float right

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/bjr44fq6/
Simply `float` everything `left` and whatever elements you want side by side `display: inline-block;` and if you don't want a particular element without any element next to it, use `clear: left, right, or both`

## HTML

```
    <header class='header'>
    <section class='container'>
        <nav class="header-right">
             <h1>Welcome Guest</h1>  <a href="https://nowhere.togo">Free Register</a>  <a href="https://nowhere.togo">Login</a>

        </nav>
        <select class="lang">
            <option>Select Language</option>
            <option>English</option>
        </select>
        <p class="gtran">Powered by Google Translate</p>
    </section>
</header>
```

## CSS

```
       .logo {
    float: left;
}
.logo a {
    display: block;
}
.container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.header {
    margin: 10px 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.header-right h1 {
    float: left;
    width: 42%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.header-right a {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.lang {
    display: block;
    float: letf;
    clear: both;
}
.gtran {
    float: float;
}
```